# django.core.cache.backends.base.InvalidCacheBackendError: Could not find backend 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache': cannot import name 'six'

Tags: django, python-3.x

`django_redis` failing to import `six` from `django.utils`

Traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /harem/reponse/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yangcoco/.virtualenvs/Django_czbk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 50, in _create_cache
    backend_cls = import_string(backend)
  File "/home/yangcoco/.virtualenvs/Django_czbk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/home/yangcoco/.virtualenvs/Django_czbk/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/yangcoco/.virtualenvs/Django_czbk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_redis/cache.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .util import load_class
  File "/home/yangcoco/.virtualenvs/Django_czbk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_redis/util.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.utils import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yangcoco/.virtualenvs/Django_czbk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/yangcoco/.virtualenvs/Django_czbk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 93, in __call__
    response = self.process_request(request)
  File "/home/yangcoco/.virtualenvs/Django_czbk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 20, in process_request
    request.session = self.SessionStore(session_key)
  File "/home/yangcoco/.virtualenvs/Django_czbk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/cache.py", line 17, in __init__
    self._cache = caches[settings.SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS]
  File "/home/yangcoco/.virtualenvs/Django_czbk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 79, in __getitem__
    cache = _create_cache(alias)
  File "/home/yangcoco/.virtualenvs/Django_czbk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 53, in _create_cache
    "Could not find backend '%s': %s" % (backend, e))
django.core.cache.backends.base.InvalidCacheBackendError: Could not find backend 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache': cannot import name 'six'
```

Using:
`django-redis 4.10.0`
`python 3.6`

Comment: This is another variant of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59191180/getting-error-cannot-import-name-six-from-django-utils-when-using-django-3-0/59191334#59191334 The `six` module from `django.utils` has been removed, and there are still some packages that depend on that.

Answer (score 2):

`django_redis` is trying to import `six` from `django.utils`

> File "/home/yangcoco/.virtualenvs/Django_czbk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_redis/util.py", line 8, in 
>       from django.utils import six

However, `six` has been removed from `django`. Check Django 3.0 [release notes here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#removed-private-python-2-compatibility-apis)

Either switch to bleeding edge django_redis or to Django 2.2 if you need to use this specific version of django_redis

Comment: @yangcoco, how did you end up solving it?

Comment: @NaderAlexan you might wanna check my answer

Answer (score 2):

You could try installing the bleeding edge version of django-redis to fix the [issue](https://github.com/niwinz/django-redis/issues/369).

This would enable you to use Django 3 that comes with [features that can change how you'll develop your app.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#enumerations-for-model-field-choices)

To do so, just install the package directly from GitHub, if you're using Pipenv like I am, just issue the following command:

```
pipenv install git+https://github.com/niwinz/django-redis.git@master#egg=django-redis
```

If you still want to stick to Django 2.X just edit the Django entry in your  Pipfile to:

```
django = "==2.*"
```

Or issue the following command:

```
pipenv install "django==2.*"
```