# Django 3.0.4 compatibility with Six package

Tags: python, django, six

I am using Django 2.2.10 for my app. I am trying to bump it up to Django 3.0.4. But it's throwing me this error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' (C:\Users\hkhatri\Desktop\capstone\fitgirl-inc\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils__init__.py)

I already have six==1.14.0 installed. Can someone please help on how to upgrade my Django version from 2.2.10 to 3.

Comment: It is not `six`, it is Django's `six`. It looks like you already upgraded, but somehow use packages that depend on Django's six: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59191180/67579

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the rest of your code and not sure how you're using six but this is how I'm using six in Django 3:

- You want to install Six with `pip`
- Add it to your apps in `settings`
- Then import it in your model `import six`
- `...six.PY3......`