# django email verification before signup allowed

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build an email verification portion of my application.  So the user enters their email, hits submit, and they will get an email with a one-time "token" or link that allows them to access the actual sign up page.  How do I go about this with the newer version of django since the

`from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator`

`from django.utils import six`

code doesn't seem to be working?

The actual error says cannot import name six from django.utils.  I see in other answers [Getting error cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' when using Django 3.0.0 latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59191180/getting-error-cannot-import-name-six-from-django-utils-when-using-django-3-0) that it has to do with six being dropped from django 3.0.  Is there a better way to do verification emails upon registration?

Answer (score 0):

Install six: pip install six

or if it is already installed

change this: 'from django.utils import six' 
for this: import six

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/
Since we expect apps to drop Python 2 compatibility when adding support for Django 3.0, we’re removing these APIs at this time.
django.utils.six - Remove usage of this vendored library or switch to six.